# tooltip for htmlwidget leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, ggvis

I'm using the wonderful leaflet package in R and I'm wondering if there is a way to have a tooltip such that:

1- the user could draw a rectangle and

2- the code could estimate the actual physical size of the rectangle (in, say, feet) given the zoom level of the map and legs of the tooltip rect

```
## This doesn't work and mixes metaphors from leaflet and ggvis
## It's just pseudocode to give intuition 
library(leaflet)
library(ggvis)

lb <- linked_brush()
map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers() %>% lb()

size <- lb()$rect_width * lb()$rect_height * map$zoom_factor
```

Comment: sorry I'm just now seeing this, but perhaps `addMeasure` in leaflet will do the trick.  `?leaflet::addMeasure` will give you the details.  Here is the code https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/R/plugin-measure.R.